# Android : how to use only link to get the app from google play

Tags: android, google-play-services

I wated only access with the help of the link to my apps in appstore

I dont want the app to appear with normal search in appstore, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for a link of just your apps as a list. This is possible in form of a list of all apps of one specific dev.

Examples:

- [Niantic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Niantic,%20Inc.) = https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Niantic,%20Inc.
- [Supercell](https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=6715068722362591614&hl=de) = https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=6715068722362591614

These links can be found by clicking on the Dev of the app when searching in the play store:
[image: Developer Link in PlayStore]

Comment: Nooo, what i want is... Consider i got an app put up in the appstore lets name it "karyelo" for instance, now if i type "karyelo" in the search bar i shouldn't get it. But instead i should access it only through Link (such as what you have shared)

Comment: So you want something like the "unlisted" parameter from Youtube? There are solutions like private apps https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en but I would recommend just sharing the apk.